# Result of Exception.ToString() is different in different projects

Tags: c#, exception, formatting

When I create nested exceptions in my test console application I'm getting the following result:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var innerException = new SomeException("Inner Error");
        var outerException = new Exception("Outer Error", innerException);
        var outerExceptionString = outerException.ToString();

        Console.WriteLine(outerExceptionString);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class SomeException : Exception
{
    public SomeException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public SomeException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "BLABLABLA";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.Exception: Outer Error ---> BLABLABLA
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The output contains the overridden string "BLABLABLA". However, If I now copy this code into my windows application, I'm getting a different result:

```
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var innerException = new SomeException("Inner Error");
    var outerException = new Exception("Outer Error", innerException);
    var outerExceptionString = outerException.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(outerExceptionString);

    // ... lots of other code
}

public class SomeException : Exception
{
    public SomeException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public SomeException(string message, Exception innerException) : base(message, innerException) { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "BLABLABLA";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.Exception: Outer Error ---> TestUtility.SomeException: Inner Error
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

As you see, it didn't include the overridden string "BLABLABLA" for some reason. I tried to test it in other windows applications but the result is the same as in console app. For some reason, I'm getting different behavior in one specific project. Is there anything that could affect the way the exception is formatted? All apps use .net framework 3.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Even though I was using the same 3.5 .net framework, at runtime my projects were pointing to different versions of mscorlib.dll (for some reason). The Exception.cs in mscorlib 2.0 version makes the output with overridden string, while in mscorlib 4.0 the code seems to be different.

Here is the Exception.ToString() method in mscorlib version 2.0:

```
public override String ToString() {
        String message = Message;
        String s;
        if (_className==null) { 
            _className = GetClassName();
        } 

        if (message == null || message.Length <= 0) {
            s = _className; 
        }
        else {
            s = _className + ": " + message;
        } 

        if (_innerException!=null) { 
            s = s + " ---> " + _innerException.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "   " + Environment.GetResourceString("Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack"); 
        }

        if (StackTrace != null)
            s += Environment.NewLine + StackTrace;

        return s;
    }
```

It directly calls _innerException.ToString().
But here is the Exception.ToString() method in mscorlib version 4.0:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return this.ToString(true, true);
}

private string ToString(bool needFileLineInfo, bool needMessage)
{
    string text = needMessage ? this.Message : null;
    string text2;
    if (text == null || text.Length <= 0)
    {
        text2 = this.GetClassName();
    }
    else
    {
        text2 = this.GetClassName() + ": " + text;
    }
    if (this._innerException != null)
    {
        text2 = string.Concat(new string[]
        {
            text2,
            " ---> ",
            this._innerException.ToString(needFileLineInfo, needMessage),
            Environment.NewLine,
            "   ",
            Environment.GetRuntimeResourceString("Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack")
        });
    }
    string stackTrace = this.GetStackTrace(needFileLineInfo);
    if (stackTrace != null)
    {
        text2 = text2 + Environment.NewLine + stackTrace;
    }
    return text2;
}
```

Now it calls some overridden method _innerException.ToString(bool, bool) and that is why it doesn't include the overridden version of ToString(). I think it will affect the old code where people were using ToString overrides. Also I don't know why at runtime I'm linked to different dll versions even though I have target framework set to 3.5 everywhere but this is a different problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you are accidentally instantiating a class `SomeException` from a different namespace than you are expecting? Your output indicates that the fully referenced type is `TestUtility.SomeException`.

To test this out, use a fully qualified namespace when instantiating `innerException` and see how that works for you.

Comment: I'm sure that I'm using a correct exception type. I tried to specify namespace, but I get the same result. Also if I go to declaration in Visual Studio, I arrive to the correct type. There are no other exception types with the same name in my app. This is weird.

Comment: That is very strange. I would try placing a breakpoint in your overridden ToString() implementation to see if it is getting called. That won't solve your problem, but it could at least confirm some suspicions. You could also place a breakpoint in SomeException's constructor just to be double-sure that it is the one getting instantiated.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I think I found why it doesn't include my overridden string. It seems that the implementation of Exception.cs is different in mscorlib.dll 2.0 and 4.0. And I was linked to different dlls in different projects even though I had the same 3.5 framework set in project properties.